# Isomorphism between subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

It's not too hard (using the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups) to show that if $G, K, H$ are finitely generated abelian groups such that $G\times H$ is isomorphic to $K\times H$, then $G$ must be isomorphic to $K$.

Does this statement hold if the groups are not finitely generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, take $G=Z, K=Z^2$ and $H=Z^{\infty}$. $G\times H$ and $K\times H$ are isomorphic to $H$.